# A binary narrow-sense primitive BCH code is always symmetric, but which book has proof of this statement?

Tags: coding-theory

I will begin with the definition of BCH code.

**Definition:**  A cyclic code of length $\tilde{n}$ over $\mathbb{F}_q$
is called a BCH code of designed distance $d$ if its
generator polynomial $g(x)$ is the least common multiple
of the minimal polynomials of $\alpha^l, \alpha^{l+1},...,\alpha^{l+d-2}$
for some $l$, where $\alpha$ is a primitive $n^{th}$ root of unity.
If $l=1$, then the code is called narrow-sense
BCH code.
If $\tilde{n}= q^{\tilde{m}}-1$, i.e. $\alpha$ is the
primitive element of $\mathbb{F}_{q^{\tilde{m}}}$, where $\tilde{m}$ being an integer,
then the BCH code is called primitive.

Now, a linear code is **symmetric** if and only if the all one code vector $\bf{1}_{\tilde{n}}$ is a valid code vector. I know that if $(x+1)\nmid g(x)$ (where $g(x)$ is the generator polynomial of a BCH code) then the code will be symmetric.
With the aforementioned definition of BCH codes, for a binary narrow-sense primitive BCH code, I can prove that $(x+1)\nmid g(x)$; but I don't understand how this condition implies that the code will be symmetric?

**I am writing a journal paper where I have state this fact that a binary narrow-sense primitive BCH code is always symmetric. But giving the proof of this statement would be beyond the scope of my research paper. Therefore, I am looking for a book or a research paper which has the proof of this statement, so that I can cite their result. So far I am not able to find any book which has the proof of that statement. I need your help in this regard.**

Comment: Out of curiosity, where are you getting the term "symmetric"? I've just never run into it for codes, myself.